# Mongoose populate undefined fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I see lot of questions about this but I can't find what is wrong. When I'm using populate to get the "Foreign Key" my field is undefined.

**User Model** **:**

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    email        : { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password     : { type: String, required: true },
    firstname    : { type: String, required: true },
    lastname     : { type: String, required: true },
    created_at   : Date,
    updated_at   : Date,
    office       : [ { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Office' } ]
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema, 'User');

module.exports = User;
```

**Office Model :**

```
var officeSchema = new Schema({
    name        : { type: String, required: true },
    address     : String,
    city        : String,
    geolocation : [ { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Geolocation' } ],
    company     : [ { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Company' } ]
});

var Office = mongoose.model('Office', officeSchema, 'Office');

module.exports = Office;
```

**Populate code :**

```
User.find({})
.populate('office')
//.populate('office', 'name') I tried this too
.exec(function (err, users) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);

    users.forEach(function(user){
        console.log('Office name: ', user.office.name);
    });
});
```

I want to get the user office name. But this `user.office.name` returns me undefined and when I do this `user.office` I can see the object with the name field. But I don't have the access to the name field.

Comment: `user.office` field is an array in your schema. Try `user.office[0].name`, etc.

Comment: Nice, you right ! Can I change my model to use populate without an array ? It will work ?

Comment: You can easily change it at the schema level by removing the the `[` & `]`.

Comment: Instead `find()` use  `findOne()`. It will return ONE record in Object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `office` field in the `userSchema` is defined as array. So, in order to access its elements, use `user.office[0].name`, `user.office[1].name`, etc.

Otherwise, use a loop:

```
user.office
    .forEach(function(each) {
        console.log('Office name: ', each.name);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. I have a question about populate. As you can see in my officeSchema I have company and geolocation object ID. It is possible to populate these two object on my user find at the same time when I populate the office ?

Comment: Yes you can. Check out either [Mongoose Deep Populate](https://github.com/buunguyen/mongoose-deep-populate) plugin or you can take a look at how Mongoose [populates across multiple levels](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).

Comment: @Westen I'm not in the same case. I'm not in the same schema. User schema don't knows the company schema. So I think Mongoose Deep Populate plugin is the best solution for the moment

Answer (score 3):

You just need to edit your query to

```
 populate({path: "office", populate: {path:"company"}})
```

It'll populate company data also.

Comment: Oh nice I can grab it with `user.office.company.name` it works thanks. But do you know if the mongoose populate performance is really good compared to SQL relationship ?

Comment: @John of course mongo is document database, the performance of mongo is better than SQL relationship.Kindly upvote if you like the answer.

Comment: Oh Okay. I heard that SQL is better to manage relationship between two table. So if NoSQL is good enough for that I will stay on mongo